# Calling methods in different classes from one button in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Edit:  So I answered my first question which was right in the Kivy docs :-). 
Basically I needed to add a propoerty to the KV file like mygridwid_widget: mygridwid and then pass that to my method get_apptime like this

```
Switch:
                id: startbutton
#                text: "Start / Stop"
#                size_hint_x: 1
                on_active: root.get_apptime(self, self.active, mygridwid)
```

Now everything compiles and I can see the system is calling the update method when active the switch. Now my problem is though is that the UI does not seem to repaint the updated Grid but when i run the debugger I can see the Grid has been created and populated with data. Anyone have a idea of what I am doing wrong?

---

I am brand new to Kivy and somewhat inexperienced with Python. My problem is I am making a simple GUI for a project. In my GUI I need to have a button that turns on the system, keeps track of test time, and then updates a Grid layout with data as long as the main switch is "on." When it's off it should not update the button. Right now I am just trying to prototype the main UI elements and latter will connect my MQTT code to push data to the system.

In my code below I specifically want to know how to call the update_data method in MyGrid class from BDdemoForm class get_apptime method here:

```
def get_apptime(self, instance, value):
        myappstate = value

        if myappstate == True:
            self.bsdemo_currenttime = time.asctime()
            #how do i call this method in this class
            root.MyGrid.update_display()

            print(myappstate)
        else:
            self.bsdemo_currenttime = "0"
            print(myappstate)
```

Anyways here is my code, main.py:

```
import time
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
#custom and helper classes
import labelb
import DeviceData
#import AppState
class TableHeader(Label):
    pass

class PlayerRecord(Label):
    pass

class BSdemoRoot(BoxLayout):
    pass

myappstate = BooleanProperty()
myappstate = False
#mygridob = MyGrid()
# class my widget
class BSdemoForm(BoxLayout):
    bsdemo_currenttime = StringProperty()
    device_data = ObjectProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(BSdemoForm, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.bsdemo_currenttime = "0"

    def get_apptime(self, instance, value):
        myappstate = value

        if myappstate == True:
            self.bsdemo_currenttime = time.asctime()
            root.MyGrid.update_display()
            #MyGrid(self).update_display()
            print(myappstate)
        else:
            self.bsdemo_currenttime = "0"
            print(myappstate)
        # sys_data = self.get_devicedata()
#create a data manager class
class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.get_tableheaders()
        self.get_devicedata()
        self.display_data()

    def get_tableheaders(self):
        self.tabledata = [
            {'LRT': 'Last Recived Time', 'Type': 'Classification Type', 'STR': 'Session Time Remaining'},
        ]

    def get_devicedata(self):
        self.data = [
            {'LRT': '8.243', 'Type': 'DJI Mavic', 'STR': '4.39'},
            {'LRT': '5.243', 'Type': 'Parrot BeBop', 'STR': 'Close'},
            {'LRT': '7.11', 'Type': 'Parrot Ebee', 'STR': 'Close'},
            {'LRT': '5.3', 'Type': 'Parrot DISCO', 'STR': '11.12'},
            {'LRT': '3.20', 'Type': 'Yuneec Typhoon', 'STR': '2.13'},
            {'LRT': '5.44', 'Type': 'Yuneec', 'STR': '5.23'},
            {'LRT': '1.12', 'Type': 'DJI Pro 4', 'STR': '1.10'},
            {'LRT': '2', 'Type': 'Parrot Sumo', 'STR': '2.3555'}
        ]

# assembles the items to be pushed into the gridlayout widget


    def display_data(self):
        self.clear_widgets()
        print(myappstate)
        for myi in xrange(len(self.tabledata)):
            print("display data method was run")
            myrow = self.create_header(myi)
            for myitem in myrow:
                self.add_widget(myitem)

        if myappstate == True:
            for i in xrange(len(self.data)):
                row = self.create_player_info(i)
                #add all the items to the widget
                for item in row:
                    self.add_widget(item)

    @classmethod
    def update_display(self):
        self.clear_widgets()
        print(myappstate)
        for myi in xrange(len(self.tabledata)):
            print("update data display was called")
            myrow = self.create_header(myi)
            for myitem in myrow:
                self.add_widget(myitem)

        if myappstate == True:
            for i in xrange(len(self.data)):
                row = self.create_player_info(i)
                #add all the items to the widget
                for item in row:
                    self.add_widget(item)



# this allows you to change the tableheader column names and number
    def create_header(self,i):
        first_column = TableHeader(text=self.tabledata[i]['LRT'])
        second_column = TableHeader(text=self.tabledata[i]['Type'])
        third_column = TableHeader(text=self.tabledata[i]['STR'])
        return [first_column, second_column, third_column]

# puts the data into the right column to build the table
    def create_player_info(self, i):
        first_column = PlayerRecord(text=self.data[i]['LRT'])
        second_column = PlayerRecord(text=self.data[i]['Type'])
        third_column = PlayerRecord(text=self.data[i]['STR'])
        return [first_column, second_column, third_column]

class BSKivyApp(App):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    BSKivyApp().run()
```

And here is my kv file BSKivy.ky.

```
#: import ListItemLabel kivy.uix.listview.ListItemLabel
#: import ListAdapter kivy.adapters.listadapter.ListAdapter

<PlayerRecord>:
    id: myplayer
    size_hint_y: None
    height: '30dp'
    width: '100dp'

    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgb: 0.2, 0.2, 0.2
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<TableHeader>:
    id: myheader
    size_hint_y: None
    height: '30dp'
    width: '100dp'

    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgb: 0.5, 0.5, 0.5
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

BSdemoRoot:
<BSdemoRoot>:
    BSdemoForm
<BSdemoForm>
    orientation: "vertical"
    #device_data: device_data_results
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        BoxLayout:
            Label:
                text: "BS Demo Interface and GUI"
        BoxLayout:
            Label:
                text: "Current Time"
                size_hint_x: 1
            Label:
                id: app_runtime_label
                text: root.bsdemo_currenttime
                size_hint_x: 1
            Switch:
                id: startbutton
#                text: "Start / Stop"
#                size_hint_x: 1
                on_active: root.get_apptime(self, self.active)

                # ; app.root.MyGrid.display_data(self)
        ScrollView:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: '200dp'

            MyGrid:
                id: mygridwid
                cols: 3
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                spacing: '1dp'

        BoxLayout:
            Label:
                text: "replace with a button"
```

Answer (score 0):

So I got this working and will close it. Basically, I had two issues. One was not understanding how to use property and ID's correctly. My second issue was a simple variable scope issue.